# Convert Json into List<T> in C# using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json string as follows

```
private string jsonCountry = @"{'BD': '880', 'BE': '32', 'BF': '226', 'BG': '359', 'BA': '387', 'BB': '+1-246', 'WF': '681'};
```

What I am trying to achieve

```
class Country
{
public string Countrypfx {get;set;}
public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}


public List<Country> GetData()
{
    private string jsonCountry = @"{'BD': '880', 'BE': '32', 'BF': '226', 'BG': '359', 'BA': '387', 'BB': '+1-246', 'WF': '681'};
    // Here, I want to return List<Country> object    
}
```

What I have tried..

```
public Country[] GetCountries()
        {
            MyCountryData myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCountryData>(jsonCountry);
            Country[] countries = myData.data;
            return countries;
        }

public class Country
    {
        public string CountryPrefix { get; set; }
        public string ContryCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyCountryData
    {
        public Country[] data { get; set; }
    }
```

Could anyone help me to get the desired output please? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json isn't in the correct format to convert it directly into a list.

First you would have to convert it into a dictionary

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonCountry);
```

Then convert it into your desired list.

```
var countries = dict.Select(d => new Country { CountryPrefix = d.Key, CountryCode = d.Value });
```

Comment: Just as a general comment, in case there are duplicate names (keys), `Dictionary<...>` would not work, use `KeyValuePair<string, string>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can convert your json to you custom object list:

```
string jsonCountry = @"{'BD': '880', 'BE': '32', 'BF': '226', 'BG': '359', 'BA': '387', 'BB': '+1-246', 'WF': '681'}";
MyCountryData conData = new MyCountryData();
conData.data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonCountry)
                .Select(x => new Country { CountryPrefix = x.Key, ContryCode = x.Value}).ToArray();
```